# How to open a file with variable in the path?

Tags: variables

`gf` runs fine with absolute or relative path.
Is it possible to open a file with variable in the path?

For example, in a tcl file:

```
...
set FILE_ROOT /user/abc
...   
read_file ${FILE_ROOT}/some/path/abc.txt
```

How to open ${FILE_ROOT}/some/path/abc.txt inside vim?

Comment: With `:exe` -- I'm quite sure it has been answered more than once.

Comment: @LucHermitte You mean manually add `g:filepath` variable and `:exe "0read" g:filePath`? Wondering if there is a more easy way.

Comment: Yep. You can also use backtick+equal depending on your version of vim -- sorry I haven't found how to type it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

- Vim user Fisher wishes to use `gf` to open a file path with an embedded variable

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Use `:execute` and `:expand` together to run a command with embedded variables
- (eg) `:let @m='/my/file/path/uu137fisher1666889936.txt' | :execute(':edit '. expand(@m))`

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- Vim version 7.4
- file editing command `gf`

#### Problem

- **Use-case scenario:** Developer wishes to use `gf` to edit a text file in vim

#### Solution

- Use `:execute` and `:expand` together to run a command with embedded variables
- (optional) create a vim function that runs the relevant commands and attach a keybinding for a custom-made `gf` variant

#### Example

#### populate a variable or register with the desired path

- `:let @m='/my/file/path/uu137fisher1666889936.txt'`

#### access that variable or register with execute() and expand()

- `:execute(':edit '. expand(@m))`

#### create a special keybinding with custom gf variant

- `:noremap <leader>gf :call My_special_gf_variant()<CR>`

#### Pitfalls

- the `gf` command is generally designed to work with literal paths, with some support for wildcard characters
- the exact use-case of interpolating or expanding variables is not depicted in `:help gf` for the Vim version referenced in this answer
- the example in this answer demonstrates how to read from a vim register instead of a vim variable, but the same basic principle applies to both contexts
- the answer will change depending on what context is responsible for resolving the relevant variable in use
- for example:

  - is it a MSFT Windows environment variable?
  - is it a BASH shell variable?
  - is it a variable declared in init.vim or some other vimscript file?
  - if declared in vimscript, has the relevant vimscript been included? (eg) `:source foobar.vim`

#### See also

- websearch://uu137fisher1666889936
- Vim `:help expand`
- Vim `:help gf`
- Vim `:help netrw-gx`